# Formating Text added via Data Sets in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I've been using Data Sets to fill alot of my graphics with Text. However I want the text to have different formatting styles (New Lines, Tabs, Bold and Italic to be specific) with certain words. For example:

"He *should* have seen it coming."

I'm using **.csv** Files for Data. Are there any "special characters" I can insert to allow this? Or any other way to do this using standard Data Sets in Photoshop (CS3)?

I want to avoid editing each file seperatly.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, text replacement in Photoshop is a bit of an all-or-nothing proposition. When it comes to text, PS is a fairly blunt instrument, and lacks the sophistication of a layout program like InDesign. You can preset the basic text styling, but any fine tuning, such as italicizing individual words, is going to have to be done by hand.

I've not tested tabs, but I expect that you can insert an actual tab in a text field in a comma-delimited file and have that honored by Photoshop. There aren't any special codes that would make this work.

That said, what you are trying to do most likely *can* be accomplished by scripting. There are plenty of helpful folks who hang out on SO and on the Adobe [Photoshop scripting forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/photoshop/photoshop_scripting). In my experience, scripters are terrifically willing to help out when asked.